# Convert datetime to varbinary inside update query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure which updates a table and I need to convert the a variable `@Birthdate datetime` to `varbinary`.

`Birthday_encrypt is varbinary`

Here is my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_UpdateUserProfile
    @Birthdate datetime
AS
BEGIN
    OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKey1
        DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate1;

    UPDATE table1 
        SET Birthday_encrypt = EncryptByKey (Key_GUID('SymmetricKey1'), 
            CONVERT(varbinary(max), @Birthdate));

    CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKey1;
END
GO
```

When I try to execute the query it returns:

> Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: What is the definition of the field Birthday_encrypt? It wouldn't have accidentally been created as, say, `varchar(max)`, would it?

Comment: and if your doing an update on a single row at a time, then convert the birthdate to a variable outside the update statement.  Then use the new variable in your update.  your update has no where clause so it looks like it will update every record in the table with that birthdate

Comment: @Brad thanks for pointing out the error. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @LaughingVergil It is a `varbinary(max)` on my table

Comment: @Odie For how to fix the issue of updating all the records?  you would need to pass some other data to the SP, like the ID in the table associated to the user's birthday you are trying to update, and add that to the where clause.

Comment: @Brad Sorry. I meant the Implicit conversion error.

Answer (score 0):

-- NOTE:  This is example to fix issue with updating all records since no ID was passed, this does not fix the conversion issue, but gives a possible way to do it better

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_UpdateUserProfile
    @UserTabkeID INT, 
    @Birthdate datetime
AS
BEGIN

    -- break it apart even more convert it first to Binary here, then encrypt it below before updating value
    DECLARE @ConvertedBirthday AS VARBINARY(MAX)
    SET @ConvertedBirthday = CONVERT(varbinary(max), @Birthdate)

    OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKey1
        DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate1;

     -- just a possible solution to pull out the conversion from being inline so doing conversion and encryption ahead of time inside the decrypt key, then close the encrpt key, and use that variable in your update

     -- NOTE as I said this will not fix your encrypt issue, just make it easier to debug by breaking it apart
     DECLARE @EncryptedValue as Varbinary(MAX)
     SET @EncryptedValue = EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('SymmetricKey1'), @ConvertedBirthday)

    CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKey1;

    UPDATE table1 
        SET Birthday_encrypt = @EncryptedValue
        Where table1.UserTableID = @UserTableID;


END
GO
```

Comment: I updated the above code to pull out the conversion a bit more so you can debug it a bit better before just inserting it