# Explicitly convert datetime to varbinary

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to convert a `datetime` column to `varbinary(100)`, but haven't had any luck. My problem is very similar to [Convert datetime to varbinary inside update query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51067958/convert-datetime-to-varbinary-inside-update-query), but I still wasn't able to develop a solution.

Here is my code:

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SymKey_TheDate_SYMMETRIC
    DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate_TheDate_Encryption

UPDATE PROFILE_DATA 
SET A29_FDATE = EncryptByKey (Key_GUID('SymKey_TheDate_SYMMETRIC'), CONVERT(varbinary(100), A29_FDATE))
FROM PROFILE_DATA
GO

CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SymKey_TheDate_SYMMETRIC
```

Here is the error I get when trying to convert `A29_FDATE` from `datetime` to `varbinary(100)`:

> Implicit conversion from data type varbinary to datetime2 is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is not for `datetime` to `varbinary(100)`, but for `varbinary` to `datetime2`. The function [EncryptByKey()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/encryptbykey-transact-sql) returns a `varbinary` that is assigned to a date field `A29_FDATE`. The output of `EncryptByKey()` needs explicit conversion if you are going to attempt it.

Something like:

```
...
SET A29_FDATE = convert(datetime2(0), EncryptByKey(...))
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Re-read your error:

> Implicit conversion from data type varbinary to datetime2 is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

You get a `varbinary` value just fine.  The error is converting it to `datetime2`.  The statement is converting it to `datetime2` when it tries to set the field 'A29_FDATE` to the varbinary value.  I assume from the field name it is a datetime2 field.  I don't think you can or should convert this to a datetime2 field.

If you are in the process of encrypting the field in your table, you will have to create a new column with the type varbinary, probably `A29_FVARBIN` (yuck), and update that to the result of your query.  Then you can drop the A29_FDATE field if you want.